# Prove that $\kappa(s) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \left|\frac{\theta (s,h)}{h}\right|$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Let $\gamma:I\subset \Reals \to \Reals^{n}$ the arc length parameterization of a curve $C\subset \Reals^{n}$.

If $\theta(s, h)$ is the angle between $T(s)$ and $T(s + h)$, show that $$
\kappa(s) = \lim_{h \to 0} \left|\frac{\theta (s, h)}{h}\right|.
$$

Indeed, I can see that geometrically this is what happens, but how can I prove it? I have tried using that
$$
\cos\theta = \langle T(s), T(s + h)\rangle,
$$
but I can't get to anything, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}$As you noted,
$$
\cos\theta(s, h) = \Brak{T(s + h), T(s)}.
$$
Here, however, it may be more convenient to note that if $T' = \kappa N$, then
$$
\sin\theta(s, h) = \Brak{T(s + h), N(s)}.
\tag{1}
$$
(Why is this true?)

Now, by definition
$$
\kappa(s)N(s) = T'(s) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{T(s + h) - T(s)}{h}.
\tag{2}
$$
Dot both sides with $N$ and see what you get.

Comment: (1) is true because $sin(\frac{\pi}{2})-\theta)=cos(\theta)$ and because $T(s)$ is orthogonal to $N(s)$ right?

Comment: I still can't get to the result, how should I dot N with the derivative(the limit on the right side)?

Comment: (i) Yes to the first; to first order, $T(s + h)$ lies in the plane spanned by $T(s)$ and $N(s)$. (ii) The dot product can be moved inside the limit and distributed through the numerator of the difference quotient. :)